# Convert two lists of same length to a dictionary in Terraform

Tags: terraform

How do I transform two lists into a dictionary while removing the duplicates in Terraform?

```
test_keys = ["Rash", "Kil", "Varsha", "Varsha"]
test_values = [1, 4, 5, 5]
```

Results:

```
{'Varsha': 5, 'Rash': 1, 'Kil': 4}
```

I can do : `toset(test_keys)` and `toset(test_values)` but I am unsure if they would retain the same order of list as the other list would be ordered accordingly.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zipmap](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/zipmap):

```
zipmap(test_keys,test_values)
```